# How to set fallback encoding to UTF-8 in Firefox?

Tags: arch-linux, firefox, character-encoding

I've written a Norwegian markdown document:

```
$ file brukerveiledning.md
brukerveiledning.md: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

I've converted it to HTML using the `markdown` command:

```
$ markdown > brukerveiledning.html <  brukerveiledning.md 
$ file brukerveiledning.html 
brukerveiledning.html: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

However, **Firefox insists on using the "windows-1252" encoding,** breaking the non-ASCII characters. I've tried setting the changing the fallback text encoding from "Default for Current Locale" (which here in the UK should be either ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8) to "Central European, ISO", "Central European, Microsoft", and "Other (incl. Western European)". None of these can display æ, ø and å. There are no Unicode options. I've also tried changing `intl.fallbackCharsetList.ISO-8859-1` in about:config to various values like `utf8`, `utf-8`, `iso-8859-1`, with no luck.

Using this `markdown` package:

```
$ pacman --query --owns "$(which markdown)"
/usr/bin/markdown is owned by markdown 1.0.1-6
```

and this locale:

```
$ locale 
LANG=en_GB.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I [tried to ask](https://github.com/waylan/Python-Markdown/issues/492#issuecomment-245383049) for a solution at the `markdown` command level, but that was rejected.

Comment: What about setting View > Text Encoding > Unicode from the Firefox menu?

Comment: @PaulNordin That's a good way to do it for one page (I had forgotten that menu even existed since they removed it by default!), but I don't think that sets the default.

Comment: Oh yea, it's only temporary. I think the problem might be elsewhere. Firefox relies on headers or meta to determine the file type. For example, I created a UTF-8 file test.html containing `åæâéè` and opened it in firefox. The output was garbage: `Ã¥Ã¦Ã¢Ã©Ã¨`. However, if I add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` to the top, it outputs properly. Not sure how you would do this for a .md file.

Comment: I also want to do this to be able to view html email from mutt by lauching firefox, still, the html file mutt produces is utf-8 without meta tags.

Comment: *"Text Encoding"* is not in the *"View"* menu (Firefox version 91.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: this has been fixed since Firefox 66**

> UTF-8-encoded HTML (and plain text) files loaded from file: URLs are now supported without `<meta charset="utf-8">` or the UTF-8 BOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/66#HTML

---

#### Historical information from 2016

The reasoning behind this behavior seems to be described in  Mozilla bugs [815551](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=815551) (Autodetect UTF-8 by default) and 
[1071816](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071816) (Support loading BOMless UTF-8 text/plain files from file: URLs)

As far as I understand it basically boils down to "*one should always specify the encoding as detection is too unreliable*".

- For non-local content you should leverage the protocol. With HTTP this would be providing the correct `charset` in the `Content-Type` Header
- For HTML content you may additionally use the Doctype, i.e. `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
- And for anything else the only standard way left ist to specify a BOM...

Mozilla devs seem to be [open for a patch](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071816#c13) that adds a preference setting, so one day it might be possible to open local BOM-less UTF-8 documents in Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Setting fallback encoding to UTF-8 in Firefox has been deliberately blocked - see bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=967981#c4.

Two ways around this that I've been looking at are:

1] Apply some trivial [patches](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1071816#c16) to the source and [build Firefox](http://ray-v.tk/building-firefox-seamonkey-thunderbird-releases-using-mercurial-sources.html) yourself to add a Unicode[UTF-8] option to Preferences|Content|Fonts & Colors|Advanced|"Fallback Text Encoding" drop-down menu.

2] Run a local [Apache] httpd server, and set up a Name-based Virtual Server, `utfx`, for the utf-8 encoded files in directory `/my/utf-8/files`. A utf-8 charset http header can then be generated, which Firefox will recognize and display the file as UTF-8 encoded. Of course, the actual file encoding has to be UTF-8!

a) /etc/httpd/httpd.conf - add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # This first-listed virtual host is also the default for *:80
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName utfx
    DocumentRoot "/my/utf-8/files"
      <Directory "/my/utf-8/files">
          Options Indexes
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
## show UTF-8 characters in file names:
    IndexOptions Charset=UTF-8
## for files with extension html or txt:
    AddCharset UTF-8 txt html
## for extensionless files:
      <Files *>
          ForceType 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
      </Files>
      <Files *\.*>
          ForceType None
      </Files>
</VirtualHost>
```

(Re)start the server - `apachectl restart` or `apachectl graceful`.

b) /etc/hosts - add the domain name for accessing the utf-8 encoded files:

```
127.0.0.1   utfx
```

The content-type info being sent by the server can be checked with wget -S <URL>:

```
wget -S http://utfx/test{æø,.txt,.html} 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep Content-Type
```

for the three file types (testæø, test.txt, test.html).
The output should be:

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

c) about:config - add New|Boolean:

```
browser.fixup.domainwhitelist.utfx  "true"
```

then just enter `utfx` in the Firefox address bar to get the files list ..

Comment: +1 for the Bugzilla link. The solutions are unfortunately very much overkill for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

As I have commented in your question I was struggling to obtain the same with the purpose of correctly displaying partial html (encoding is known but there's no meta tag for encoding) from Mutt in Firefox through Mailcap.

In the end I've figure out a command that works, and which may help you too:

- `uconv --add-signature -f %{charset} -t UTF-8 %s | sponge %s && firefox -new-tab %s & sleep 5`

I've discovered that when your UTF-8 encoded file contains BOM, Firefox then assumes it's UTF-8. So I've used the `uconv` command to add the BOM signature. Assume that `%{charset}` is the input charset and `%s` is the filename. The `sponge` tool (from the `moreutils` package) helps changing the file inplace and the `sleep` is just so that Mutt doesn't delete the file before Firefox finishes loading it.

I have not found any other option to set a fallback encoding in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

If setting the fallback for only offline files, to UTF-8, is sufficient for you, then you can go to `about:config` and set the value of `intl.charset.fallback.utf8_for_file` to `true`.

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664676/mozilla-firefox-set-a-default-character-encoding-to-utf8))

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to [produce a complete HTML file with an encoding declaration](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/issues/492#issuecomment-282995676):

```
pandoc --metadata=pagetitle=Brukerveiledning --output=./brukerveiledning.html --standalone --to=html ./brukerveiledning.md
```

Shortened (less explicit and produces warnings):

```
pandoc --standalone ./brukerveiledning.md > ./brukerveiledning.html
```